# jQuery smooth scroll not working

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, anchor

My website is not smoothscrolling when I press fork and want it to go to page 2.
I included the jQuery script I used inside of the HTML section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Smooth scrolling to element IDs
    $('a[href^=#]:not([href=#])').on('click', function () {
        var element = $($(this).attr('href'));
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: element.offset().top },'normal', 'swing');
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try wrapping it inside a $(function(){ ... code goes here ... });

Answer (score 1):

Use it inside `$(function () {})` as you are loading before the DOM is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // Smooth scrolling to element IDs
    $('a[href^=#]:not([href=#])').on('click', function () {
        var element = $($(this).attr('href'));
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: element.offset().top },'normal', 'swing');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```